# Why does my list have extra double brackets?

Tags: python, arrays, list, join, append

```
arr_list = []
arr = ['5', '6', '2', '4', '+']

arr_list.append([''.join(arr[0:4])])
print(arr_list)
```

Ouput: `[['5624']]`

Why does the output have 2 sets of square brackets? I only want one.

Thanks in advnace.

Comment: Contrarily to other languages (eg scheme), in python `.append` means "add an element to a list", not "concatenate another list to a list (that would be `.extend`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr_list = []
arr = ['5', '6', '2', '4', '+']
arr_list.append(''.join(arr[0:4]))
print(arr_list)
```

simply remove the brackets from the third row

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
arr_list.append(''.join(arr[0:4]))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You're appending a list to arr_list.

Use this instead:

```
arr_list.append(''.join(arr[0:4]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets around what you are appending:

```
>>> arr_list = []
>>> arr = ['5', '6', '2', '4', '+']
>>> arr_list.append(''.join(arr[0:4]))
>>> arr_list
['5624']
```

Or you could use [`list.extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) rather than [`list.append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

```
>>> arr_list = []
>>> arr = ['5', '6', '2', '4', '+']
>>> arr_list.extend([''.join(arr[0:4])])
>>> arr_list
['5624']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
arr_list.append(''.join(arr[0:4]))
```

or

```
print(''.join(arr[0:4]))
```